# Solving vector equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, system, equation

How can I solve a system of this kind in matlab?:
a + b + c = 0
a + d + e = 0
...etc

where each of this symbolic variables (they are previously defined with "syms") is in R^3,
for example:

a = [0 R1 R2];
b = [0 R3*cos(alpha) R3*sin(alpha)];

...etc (R1, R2, R3, .. are also symbolic variables, but one dimensional, ie: scalars)

I did search a lot but everyone solves systems of scalars, not of vectors.
In this case every vector equation represents 3 scalar equations

I know I could reformat the whole system into a matrix and solve Ax=0 but that would be a lot of work since these are 39 equations.

Thank you very much

Comment: Reformulating as a matrix sounds like the natural thing to do.  Why would it be a lot of work?

Comment: @oli-charlesworth Hmm, lets see, I would have to transform this: "-N_9_13 - N_10_13 - N_11_13 - N_12_13 + R_13 = 0", into these three: "-N_9_13(1) - N_10_13(1) - N_11_13(1) - N_12_13(1) + R_13(1) = 0",   "-N_9_13(2) - N_10_13(2) - N_11_13(2) - N_12_13(2) + R_13(2) = 0",  "-N_9_13(3) - N_10_13(3) - N_11_13(3) - N_12_13(3) + R_13(3) = 0"

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you've written there, but it sounds like all of your coefficients etc. are maintained as separately-named variables.  If you hadn't done that (i.e. used an array/matrix instead), then this would be trivial!

Comment: @oli-charlesworth That is a good point

Comment: @OliCharlesworth is there a way to create the matrix automatically? I now have Eqs = [vectorEqn1(1); vectorEqn1(2); vectorEqn1(3); vectorEqn2(1); .....]